# FormsAuthentication.SignOut don't work on the firefox 3 (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, firefox-3

I'm using this code in login page. This is work fine.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
               1, // Ticket version
               eUserName.Text,
               DateTime.Now, 
               DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
               true,
               "administrator",
               FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);


        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
           hash);

        // Set the cookie's expiration time to the tickets expiration time
        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        // Add the cookie to the list for outgoing response
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

But when i logout using FormsAuthentication.SignOut or asp:LoginStatus control this is don't logout. this seems logged on. When i testing on the internet explorer 8, this successfully logout.

What happing on the firefox?
How can i do fix this problem?

Thanks

ebattulga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with FireFox and FormsAuthentication is that FireFox doens't seem to delete the auth cookie on SignOut. 3 things you can try:

1) After calling the SignOut method, clear the cookies like this => `Response.cookies.clear()`
2) Try calling `Session.abandon` before your SignOut call
3) You can also try the following: `Response.Expires = 0, Response.Cache.SetNoStore(), Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")`

Hope those help!