# ASP.NET Forms Authentication Cookie Differences in Between IE and Firefox

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox, forms-authentication

Using ASP.NET forms authentication if I have forms authentication timeout set to 10 minutes I get the folloiwng behaviour.

**If I set the time on my client machine to be half an hour in the future, I can never log in Internet Explorer but I can in Firefox. **

I guess as the server sets the forms authentication cookie timeout value and check's it each time a page gets posted it dosn't matter what the time on the client PC is. However I am interested in understanding the difference between IE and firefox and why the behave in different ways in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox handles cookies differently than IE, I had a very similar problem with Firefox not deleting cookies when I called SignOut().  This SO post helped me solve that issue, might help you with this as well:

[FormsAuthentication.SignOut don't work on the firefox 3 (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220523/formsauthentication-signout-dont-work-on-the-firefox-3-asp-net)